# How to subtract when uncheck a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code where if I check a checkbox it adds the value to total, but if I uncheck it, it doesn't subtract the value

```
Private Sub CheckBox11_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim sValue As String
Dim sAdd As Boolean

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set ws = Sheet2

If CheckBox11.Value = True Then
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sValue = wf.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, ws.Range("A4:R" & LastRow), 13, False)
    
    TextBox11.Value = sValue & " €"
    sAdd = True
Else
    TextBox11.Value = ""
    sValue = "0"
    sAdd = False
End If

Call TotalValue(sValue, sAdd)

End Sub
```

Total value function :

```
  Function TotalValue(BoxValue As String, sAdd As Boolean, Optional Desc As String) As String

Dim auxDesc As Double
Dim auxValue As Double

If UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = "0" Then

    If sAdd = True Then
        UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = BoxValue
    End If
    
Else

    If sAdd = True Then
        UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = CStr(CDec(UserForm1.TextBox17.Value) + CDec(BoxValue))
    Else
        UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = CStr(CDec(UserForm1.TextBox17.Value) - CDec(BoxValue))
    End If
    
End If

If Desc <> "" Then
    auxDesc = Left(Desc, Len(Desc) - 1) / 100
    auxValue = CDec(UserForm1.TextBox17.Value) * auxDesc

    UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = CStr(CDec(UserForm1.TextBox17.Value) - auxValue)
    
End If
    
End Function
```

What I want is if I uncheck the box to subtract the total value, if I check it adds the value on total , if I uncheck it keeps "added" doesn't subtract :(

Any help?

Comment: What to substract, if the subtraction takes place only if  `BoxValue` is "0" (`CDec(BoxValue) = 0`)? Is it anything I missed? What do you try accomplishing, please?

Comment: Imagine, search box select a car. after selecting a car, i have about 20 checkbox, imagine changing the Oil of the car, you press Oil it adds for example 50$ to the total value.

What is happening is , if i uncheck the "Oil checkbox" it does not go back to 0, the total value stays on 50$ instead of going to 0

Comment: I can imagine that, but I am looking to your code. If the check box value is `True`, then `sValue` takes some value, if not, it is "0". Then you call `TotalValue` 'telling' to it to subtract nothing... And it substracts nothing.

Comment: Instead of decreasing 0, using `UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = CStr(CDec(UserForm1.TextBox17.Value) - CDec(BoxValue))`, you could simple use `UserForm1.TextBox17.Value = 0)`...

Comment: Already got it, in svalue = "0" should be the lookup and the last row.

Comment: The idea was to not subtract it! Just to use it or simple 0...